# Apply CSS to Typography Material UI

Tags: material-ui

Im trying to apply css to a Typography element but it does nothing; I have tried the same css on another div element and it works but it simply does not apply to Typography.
This is my Typography element:

```
<Typography
  variant="title"
  classname={classes.detailTitle}
>
   Details:
</Typography>
```

And this is my css:

```
detailTitle: {
        textDecoration: 'underline'
    }
```

Any clues?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a slight typo in your Typography html, it needs to say className where you have classname. This is react specific, for more info take a look here https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html

Comment: That was it...nice! Thanks a lot, spent lot of time looking for the solution; thought it was something about the element.

Comment: No prob, best of luck!

Comment: @Marcelo maybe try using better editor lol. Usually editors like `VSCode` does catch those kind of typos.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Material UI component's `classes` property to set its style. 
Check this page https://material-ui.com/api/typography/#css

Example:

```js
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  h3: {
    fontSize: '48px',
    fontWeight: '600'
  },
})
)

const TextComp = (props) => {
  const classes = useStyles()
  return (
    <Typography
      variant='h3' component='h3'
      classes={{ h3: internalClasses.h3 }}
    >
      {header}
    </Typography>
  )
}
```